# How to create manyToMany connection where owner Entity can have more than one owned Entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need three Entities - users, orders and products. Order can have several products inside, and products can be in many orders. But in one order we can have several similar products. How to organize it using hibernate?

I think that one of the ways is to create another Entity - OrderProducts, but what mapping I need to use? Or is there another and simple way to do it?

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Order_Products",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
    private List<Product> products;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Order() {
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private float price;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private List<Order> orders = new LinkedList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public void addOrder(Order order){
        orders.add(order);
    }
}
```

I need **order_products** table to have quantity column, but i dont know how.

```
Hibernate: create table order_products (order_id int4 not null, product_id int4 not null)
Hibernate: create table orders (id int4 not null, date date, user_id int4, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table product (id int4 not null, name varchar(255), price float4 not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table users (id int4 not null, fullname varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by naming this new entity properly: `OrderedProduct`.

How many ordered products can an order contain? one, or several? Several, right?

So the association between `Order` and `OrderedProduct` would be an `XxxToMany`. Is it a `OneToMany` or a `ManyToMany`?

Well, the `OrderedProduct` contains the quantity of a product that has been ordered for **one** specific order, right? And its table contains the ID of **one** order, right? So it's linked to **one** specific order. So the association can only be a `OneToMany`.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of order row entity. I suggest adding quantity field into it. It can contains some extra fields like product price or discount, etc..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_row")
public class OrderRow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    Order order;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "product_id")
    Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
    Integer quantity;
}
```

I would recommend to use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in every `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotation

Now you can edit your Order entity adding orderRows field

```
@Table(name = "orders") 
public class Order {
  // fields

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
  FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<OrderRow> orderRows = new HashSet<>();

  // getters, setters
}
```